# How to access SceneBuilder 2 samples through netBeans

Tags: java, netbeans

I am trying to access and Run the IssueTrackingLite.fxml file from the Scene Builder 2 samples which I have downloaded. 
I have unzipped/extracted the whole samples zip file into the Netbeans Projects folder in my workspace folder, which I use to run JavaFx samples. 
But the neither the the entire SB 2 samples zip file, or any of the sample files contained there-in(IssueTrackingLite.fxml, SceneBuilder Hello World etc), appear in the NetBeans projects folder when I try to find/open them through -Open- Projects- in the NetBeans IDE.
What is the correct method of accessing all of the sample files in the Scene Builder 2 samples zip file i have downloaded.???
I have Scene Builder 2 succesfully downloaded and configured to run through the NetBeans IDE and I can open and create a new FXMLDocument.fxml/project in the Scene Builder window through NetBeans.

Comment: How did you find the zip? All my googling for a  Scene Builder 2 samples zip file came up with squat.

Comment: I googled the question as to where I might find Scene Builder 2 and the samples, and up came a stackoverflow posting where someone had asked the same question and there was a reply with all of the relevant links which i followed and downloaded everything and have Scene Builder and samples working OK now.

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me, I will go through some details in case it is of use.

I followed the first link you gave:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafxscenebuilder-1x-archive-2199384.html

Clicked the accept license. and then

http://download.oracle.com/otn/java/javafx_scenebuilder/2.0-b20/javafx_scenebuilder_samples-2_0.zip

unzipped the javafx_scenebuilder_samples-2_0.zip file.

Used File -> Open Project. Selected the IssueTrackingLite folder. (Note if a folder doesn't have one of the kinds of files Netbeans looks for you can't select it. In this case I believe it is looking for an nbproject subdirectory and a build.xml file, both of which are in that directory. If you get one of the bundles of Netbeans from https://netbeans.org/downloads/index.html that doesn't include Java SE support. ie( C++ or HTML 5 & PHP) it would also might not recognize this project type. )

I had an issue where after openning the project it complained there were unresolved dependencies which turned out to be, that it needed a platform called JDK 1.8. It was solved fairly easily by adding a Java Platform. Hopefully you won't have that issue.

After that Run -> Build Project and Run -> Run Project both worked.

Double clicking the IssueTrackingLite.fxml file in the Projects tab, brought up Scene Builder.

Answer (score 0):

Glad  indeed that those links were of some use to you and thanks for your advice on resolving possible and potential pitfalls.
In the interim I discovered that the problem was that although I had scene builder 2 installed and all of the necessary samples unzipped etc into the correct directory, in the NetBeans IDE which I am using for all of the JavaFX/ Scene Builder samples, I hadn't established a correct pathfile within NetBeans IDE setup / configuration... as to where the Scene Builder standalone tool is located .... everything was in the right place, just not able to talk to each other.
Thunderbirds are GO ... for now ...